# Professionally/Professional

Tags: meaning, ielts

which **word "Professionally,professional"** is right in this sentence and why
-Many **professionally/professional** agricultural advisors were hired to boost the significantly declining industry.

Comment: Adverbs: professionally dressed visitors. Professionally painted rooms. They painted the room professionally. You might want to review adverbs.

Answer (score 0):

> Many professionally/professional agricultural advisors were hired to boost the significantly declining industry.

It has to be *professional*, the adjective, for describing the advisors.

*professionally agricultural advisors* would not make sense.

Edit

Also, it should be *agriculture*, rather than *agricultural*.

> professional agriculture advisors

Comment: They are not 'agricultural in a professional way'!

Answer (score 0):

answer= professional, because you are describing a characteristic of the agricultural advisors.

if you wanted to use “professionally”, that is describing their work instead of the people. you could say “the agricultural advisors work professionally at 9-5 jobs”